# Class name is the same as namespace issue

Tags: swift, enums, namespaces, cocoapods

I have an interesting problem involving two different Cocoapods that have a public enum with the same name.

With implicit namespacing this isn't normally a problem except that both Cocoapods have a class that is the same as their target name.

So if I import both Cocoapods in the same file referencing the enum with the same name generates a "enum-name is ambiguous for type lookup in this context", and if I attempt to reference the enum by ModuleName.enum Swift says ModuleName does not have a member named enum.

Presumably this is because the class, and not the namespace doesn't have a member named enum. Anyone know a way around this ?

Here's what this looks like in code:

Cocoapod A:

```
public enum Test {

}

public class A {

}
```

Cocoapod B:

```
public enum Test {

}

public class B {

}
```

Other file:

```
import A
import B

// Results in "A does not have a member named Test"
var test: A.Test = A.Test(rawValue: "a")

// Results in "Test is ambiguous for type lookup in this context"
var test: Test = Test(rawValue: "a")
```

Answer (score 4):

One needs to import the specific type to bring it into your files namespace before other like named types.

I'll use the `SwiftMessages` framework as an example, there the enum `Theme` clashes with like named class in another framework.

`SwiftMessages` also exists as a class within the framework, and Swift always thinks I want to access the class when I type `SwiftMessages.Theme`.

```
import enum SwiftMessages.Theme
```

Now you can use `Theme`

```
var theme: Theme
```

and it will be the expected theme.

If you still have clashes, create a separate source file

```
// e.g. SwiftMessages+Support.swift
import enum SwiftMessages.Theme

typealias SwiftMessagesTheme = SwiftMessages.Theme
```

And then use it elsewhere:

```
var theme: SwiftMessagesTheme
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy workaround for this, although I'm not sure why Swift doesn't like the `Namespace.ClassName` syntax.

Create a new file and add this code:

```
import A

typealias ATest = Test
```

Then, in your file you can do:

```
import B

var testA: ATest = ATest(rawValue: "a")
var testB: Test = Test(rawValue: "a")
```

Alternatively, you could create an equivalent typealias file for BTest as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.x and Xcode 10 the `typealias` solution doesn't work.

Instead you can use `Module.Class`, in your case just use `A.Test` or `B.Test`.